# Recursive directory copy in perl preserving mode and ownership, without content

Tags: perl, recursion, copy

Using perl I would like to locally copy a directory structure without the content, but preserving owner and mode. I found [File::Copy::Recursive](http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/File-Copy-Recursive-0.38/Recursive.pm) which provides `dircopy` that does everything except for preserving the ownership. Is there a way to achieve this without explicitly traversing old and new directories and comparing owners? Of course, somewhere in the implementation this needs to happen, but I was wondering if it is already implemented somewhere so that I don't have to reinvent this.

EDIT: It turns out `dircopy` does copy also files, so its not what I want.

Comment: Yes, mode is preserved, this works for me. What is lacking for me is preservation of ownership, which is not the same as mode.

Comment: You can't preserve ownership unless you're root. Are you root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up roling my own:

```
sub dirCopy {
    my $old = shift;
    my $new = shift;
    if( -d $new ){return(1)}
    my $old_base = dirname($old);
    my $new_base = dirname($new);
    unless( -d $new_base ){dirCopy($old_base, $new_base)}
    my @old_stat = stat($old) or die("Could not stat $old");
    my $old_mode = $old_stat[2];
    my $old_uid = $old_stat[4];
    my $old_gid = $old_stat[5];
    mkdir($new) or die("Could not mkdir $new");
    chown($old_uid, $old_gid, ($new)) or die("Could not chown $new");
    chmod($old_mode, ($new)) or die("Could not chmod $new");
    return(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need portability, I'd use the system-provided tools. They'll be faster and more reliable. `tar` can recreate permissions and ownership.

If you wanted to copy the directories and the files therin, it would be simple:

```
( cd "$SRC" ; tar c ) | ( cd "$DST" ; tar x --preserve --same-owner )
```

But you asked to recreate the directory structure without its contents. For that, you can use the following:

```
( cd "$SRC" ; find -type d -exec \
   sh -c 'tar c --no-recursion "$@" | ( cd "$DST" ; tar x --preserve --same-owner )' \
      dummy {} + )
```

`$SRC` and `$DST` are the base source and destination directories respectively.

Of course, these commands need to execute as `root` in order to preserve ownership.

Comment: That is a sweet solution. After reevaluating my needs, I ended up roling my own, which I will post.